# Power-leveling in Neverwinter

Tags: neverwinter

I was playing with a character to NeverWinter but left the game in level 16. Now I want to play with a friend who is in level 40. I want to rise level 40 as soon as possible. What is the best way for power-leveling?

I have heard that there are foundry quests for that but I can't identify them in the foundry quest list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your friend run though the areas you have access to. you will lose the XP for kills but completing quests is more important. So just have the powerful friend kill low level enemies and you focus on quest objectives.

Comment: Definitely doesn't take long to run through quests, which is the bulk of the experience earning. Don't forget to invoke a few times daily, too. The first invoke is worth a standard quest reward for your level, the second half, the third a quarter. It's good, free experience that adjusts to your level.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a 25% experience buff by invoking at least twice each day.  That works for all forms of leveling:

- Killing things
- Quests (having a friend power level you here is a good idea)
- Leadership tasks
- Invoking XP gains

Additional tip for leveling a new character: Get 2 gold from an old character and buy the white quality control wizard companion.  It will nuke anything and everything out of your way up to around level 10, and is a decent companion until at least level 20.

**UPDATE**

With the introduction of alliances, you can level extremely quickly by running the hardest heroic encounters (HE's) in a stronghold. You can easily gain 4-5 levels in a 30 minute HE session and earn some nice treasure to boot.

Slot the best Azure enchantments you can get your hands on in Utility slots for a nice XP bonus.